# How can I debug an Angular JS $http.put that seems not to do anything?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these two functions:

```
   var getConfigs = function () {
       var defer = $q.defer();
       $http.get('/api/Config/Get')
           .success(function (data) {
               defer.resolve({
                   configs: data,
               });
           });
       return defer.promise;
   }

   var putConfigs = function(config) {
       // When I check here I see config has some values
       $http.put('/api/Config/Put', config);
   }
```

When I call `getConfigs()` I see data coming across in fiddler and $scope.configs is populated. However when I call `putConfigs($scope.config);` then I don't see anything in fiddler and no message goes to my host controller.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong. Is there another way I can debug what is happening other than using Chrome to step through the code and fiddler to watch what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the extent of your code, then you're not completing the $http cycle. You need to handle the response.

```
var myPut = $http.put('/api/config/put', config);
myPut.then(function(data){
    //things that should happen when the call is successful go here
}, function(data){
    //things that should happen when the call is not successfful go here
});
```

If you're handling the response, you'll need to post that code before anyone can help you.